# I am unable to vagrant up

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I am using a [file](https://github.com/LearnWebCode/vagrant-lamp) from GitHub

It has a vagrant file with it. When I run vagrant up command in my terminal, I get an error.

[image]

The terminal should show READ ABOVE message when successful download

[image]

I want to type in the address to the site on my browser to start a local development server.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, instead edit your question, copy the text into it and use the code formatting tool (=indent with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty old file and the repo was using [puphpet](https://puphpet.com) but this project seems dead for 2 years, the website is down.

In your case, vagrant is trying to download the box from internet but the owner of this box hosted it under the puphpet domain not available anymore

I am not sure what's the best way to help now:

- find another more recent example and start from there
- if you want to fix this, you will need https://github.com/LearnWebCode/vagrant-lamp/blob/master/puphpet/config.yaml#L6 and use a different box available on vagrant site, ubuntu 16.04 is pretty old now but you can search one from [vagrant box](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=&q=ubuntu1604-x64)